# How can I validate the Path for a javafx image

Tags: image, validation, javafx, path, fxml

I want to check if my javafx image with a defined path exists.
If it doesn't exist jet in the file System, I don't want to load it.
But to do this I have to check the path first.
I need to know if there is a function to validate it.

Here is the constructor where I want to create the Image:

```
public TestController(String title){
    this.model = title;
    this.modelurl = "images/Test/"+model+"/uebersicht.png";
    this.farbImg = new Image(modelurl, 1500, 900, true, true);
}
```

Does anybody know a smart way to do this?

Comment: What happens if the path isn't valid/doesn't exist ?

Comment: @Calips
Hi again :)
Then this exception will be thrown:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found

Comment: Hi again! :P Then you got your answer :) you need to catch that exception :D because basically the image won't load since the path doesn't exist :D

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument. Are you sure it's because the path or the image doesn't exist ?

Comment: Thank you :)
Thaought there would be a more elegant way but this would do, too.

Comment: No problem, Though i don't know of another way to do it since you put the path manually  you should check it yourself if it's true, else if the OS can't find the path (during exceution) you need to check for that exception :D Good luck for the rest :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try{
  this.farbImg = new Image(modelurl, 1500, 900, true, true);
} catch (Exception e){ //Change the "Exception" class by the adequate exception
  //URL Not valid or whatever exception it caught
  //Do something
  System.out.println("Exception thrown  :" + e);
}
```

Though i don't have an IDE here to test, but i think it will be an IOException.